# JavaFX moving object on transparant window 25% cpu usage

Tags: java, performance, canvas, javafx, drawing

When I move an simple circle in javafx on an transparant window and window I get over 20% cpu usage.
But when i disable the Transparant window it is only using 2% cpu usage.

First I throught I did something wrong so I found an [example](https://www.mkyong.com/javafx/javafx-animated-ball-example/) which moves an ball on the screen and made it fullscreen and transparant but it was also using 30% cpu. 
Now I don't know it anymore does someone know what I'm doing wrong? 
Here is my code:

```
 @Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
    int w = gd.getDisplayMode().getWidth();  // fullscreen
    int h = gd.getDisplayMode().getHeight(); // fullscreen

    Pane canvas = new Pane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(canvas, w, h);
    Circle ball = new Circle(10, Color.RED);
    ball.relocate(0, 10);

    stage.initStyle(TRANSPARENT); // added this line for transparancy 
    scene.setFill(null); // added this line for transparancy 

    canvas.getChildren().add(ball);

    stage.setTitle("Moving Ball");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

    Bounds bounds = canvas.getBoundsInLocal();
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(3),
            new KeyValue(ball.layoutXProperty(), bounds.getMaxX() - ball.getRadius())));
    timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.play();
}
```

Comment: Perhaps the same issue as this bug report: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8091556

Comment: Jup think its the same bug, still sad that it hasn't been fixed yet since the report is since 2011

Comment: probably not the answer you want, but you could consider using Swing for this particular interface until the issue is resolved?